# Where I must contain business logic of my application?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture, business-logic

After read a lot of articles about right architecture application, I still have a question: where app business logic must contains? 
Becouse someone told, that logic must contains in models (skinny controllers), another said that models must contain only Database operations logic.

For example:

In my project (online shop) I have a products filter, that used in CategoryController and filtered by Products and Parameters table. So it's not a controller and not a model. I solved it by creation of new directory named Filters (yes, there are few different filters), and contain all logic there. 
But i dont know is it right solution? I think not, but I dont know how to build it correctly.

So here is my questions:

1. Did i do the right thing?
2. Where I must contain business logic?

Thanks and have a nice day!

P.s
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Same as for your russian version of question - __primarily opinion-based__.

Comment: what framework is your project (online shop)

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's down to preferences. As long as you are using the correct standards, you should be fine!

So in Laravel, I use `Models` strictly for database operations. I also create a folder called `Services` and another folder called `Hydrators`

My services in the service folder handles the business logic e.g grabbing data from the models and any logical operations. My hydrators take the data and sort it in the way I want the data to be presented to the view.

Both my services and hydrators take on the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074) as this allows me to reuse the same code elsewhere to avoid code duplication!

My controllers are just an entry point to the back end and only do two things; call the services and stitch the ones needed together and return a result (a result could be anything from JSON to a view with data).

This is just my personal way of doing things. Others may have a different way.

Comment: Thank you for so detailed response.

I will try to use your technique.